# Multiple options for user, some not available

Tags: lists, ux-designer, ux-integration

I want to create an option for the user to choose between lessons.
There are more than 4 lessons that are in the picture.

For every lesson there are 3 options:

1. The lesson is full - the user can't register to this lesson
2. The user can register to this lesson
3. The user already registered to this lesson.

[image]

I think how can I do this?
Make every option block in different color? Where to put the button to register (where the YES NO buttons are now?)

Or make the blocks clickable to register?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. For now I understand you want each lesson to show if they are available to the user or not, and if that’s the case to show a register button. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use color to show which is which, but I wouldn't make the whole lesson block one color. I wouldn't make the whole block as a button either.

Just make a button that says available/full/registered and give that a color. You could use the traffic lights for this (red = full, green = registered, yellow = open spots) or RGB (red = full, green = open, blue = registered) but it could be too busy looking.

Personally I'd go with something like this:

[image]

Which doesn't only show if you can enroll in a class, but also how full it is or how long you still have to decide.

Comment: +1 good suggestion! The only thing I'd change is swapping the shades of the progress bar. I'd make the "populated" side the dark shade and fill it left to right, only because it seems natural to "fill in" the bar as a class becomes more full.